# Angular 9 ngModel not clearing default selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to autofill a text box based on the state from another component. Which works fine. But when I go to add ngModel to the text box to take in the value when submitting the form. The value is cleared and not displayed to the user.

```html
<div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillMode" class="row">
  <label>Mode of Transport</label>
  <input type="text" value="{{state.type}}" readonly />
</div>

<div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillStop" class="row">
  <label>Nearby Stop / Station</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    value="{{state.stopName}}"
    [(ngModel)]="stopName"
    readonly
  />
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see in the image the text shows up when there is no ngModel placed on the input. But when there is a ngModel it is not shown.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [(ngModel)] for both text boxes

```
 <div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillMode" class="row">
        <label>Mode of Transport</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state.type" readonly>
    </div>
        
    <div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillStop" class="row">
        <label>Nearby Stop / Station</label>
        <input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="state.stopName" readonly>
    </div>
```

Note: **[(ngModel)]** is for two-way binding which will update data from component to view and vice-versa.

In two-way data binding, automatic synchronization of data happens between the Model and the View. Here, change is reflected in both components. Whenever you make changes in the Model(.ts), it will be reflected in the View(html) and when you make changes in View, it will be reflected in Model.

This happens immediately and automatically, ensures that the HTML template and the TypeScript code are updated at all times.

Answer (score 0):

ngModel creates a two-way binding. In your case, you probably don't have **stopName** attribute in your component and that's why when you add NgModel you get empty input field. Your code is redundant in this case, value and ngModel both try to set the input value.

Try removing value and set existing attributes to ngModel.

```
    <div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillMode" class="row">
      <label>Mode of Transport</label>
      <input type="text" value="{{state.type}}" readonly>
    </div>

   <div *ngIf="autoFill; else noFillStop" class="row">
     <label>Nearby Stop / Station</label>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state.stopName" readonly>
   </div>
```

You can also try to use **FormControl**, which gives option to set, get, clear, check the validity, ... values from specific formControl or from whole form.

Here is a small implementation in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-thffzh)
Don't forget to import ReactiveFormModule